# Error when using javascript component in typescript file Vue.js

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js

I have a javascript file and I am trying to use in another file, but this file is defined typescript " < script lang="ts" >".

> this.$toast.error('Text ');

When i am using this command in a vue.js file standard I don't have errors but when I used it in typescript file I receive the next error:

> Property '$toast' does not exist on type
> 'MyTypescriptComponent'.

I mention that it is working but i receive that error.

Answer (score 0):

There is a workaround to dismiss the error, for the example you can do this:

```
toast: any = this.$toast;
mounted() {
  this.toast = this.$toast;
}
yourMethod() {
  this.toast.error('Text ');
}
```